# After installing I18n in Rails Spree application rake db:migrate does not work and methods and pages cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, spree, rails-i18n

In my Ruby on Rails Spree Commerce app I try to run

```
bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations 
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

via ssh on the server since I think that will solve some issues I am having with methods that cannot be found (e.g., `NoMethodError in Spree::OrdersController#populate
undefined method`tax_total='` and even products that cannot be displayed after I added localization with I18n.

It aborts and says:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Index name 'index_spree_adjustments_on_source_type_and_source_id' on table 
'spree_adjustments' already exists
```

See [full gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8511297). I am not even sure if I need to run these two commands on the server. I did do it locally first too and then deployed with Capistrano.

Well I hope someone can explain a bit more about this and provide some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, the method `.tax_total=` is being called on a `Spree::Order` that does not have that method defined.

Perhaps you are missing an attribute declaration?

**EDIT**

In your migration file, comment the line that say

```
add_index("problematic index")
```

Comment: What do you mean with missing an attribute declaration?  Please note that I just got the Spree code and have not changed anything in the models or controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out that I installed Bootstrap 2 which is used in Spree Stable-2-0. When I changed to Bootstrap 3 (called Spree_Bootstrap_Frontend) [here](https://github.com/200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend) all methods worked again!